# Error stopping Advantage service. Error code 172

Tags: advantage-database-server

When running the adsstamp.exe to update an Advantage license the following error appears:

Error stopping Advantage service. Report this error to Advantage technical support. Error Code 172.

Additional info:
- Logged in as Admin (Domain admin)
- Server 2008 X64 (not R2)

Can anyone shed any light on this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running ADSStamp.exe the utility must stop the Advantage Service in order to modify the server executable (ADS.exe).  If the service failed to stop this error could be returned.

By default, if users are connected to ADS when you attempt to stop the service a message box is displayed asking if you really want to terminate the service.  However, this message box is shown on the console only (and with 2008 I think it may never be shown).  You can set an option to suppress the message box in the configuration utility, but it won't take effect until next time ADS is stopped and restarted.

I would recommend manually stopping the Advantage service.  If you have users in the database have them log out or kill the connections (you can do this in ARC) and then stop the service.  As a LAST resort (I recommend against this) you could also kill the "ads.exe" task.

Once ads.exe is no longer running you should be able to use adsstamp.exe to update the license without any issue and then start the ADS server.